# Get users according to months of year

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code for chart to get the users report for each month of current year:

```
$numbers_months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];

$users = [];

foreach ($numbers_months as $value) {
    // dd(date("Y") . '-' . $value);
    $users[] = User::where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %m')"), date("Y") . '-' . $value)->count();
}

dd($users);
```

The output of this is ;

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
  6 => 0
  7 => 0
  8 => 0
  9 => 0
  10 => 0
  11 => 0
]
```

I have 11 users in DB for this month!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sta How can I get the users count of each month of a year

Comment: Laravel Eloquent has built-in `whereMonth` and `whereYear` methods that would simplify this a good bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$numbers_months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

foreach ($numbers_months as $value) {

   $users[] = User::where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%c')"), date("Y") . '-'  . $value)->count();
 }
dd($users);
```

Another solution from @jszobody :

```
$users[] = User::whereMonth('created_at',$value)->whereYear('created_at', date("Y"))->count();
```